# String concatenation of endpoint modify the comportment of a Get request

Tags: apex, api, httprequest, httpresponse

```
string id = '12345'; // will be set dynamically
string endpoint = 'https:/sameEnpoint/leads/' + '12345'; //opt1
string endpoint = 'https:/sameEnpoint/leads/' +  id; //opt2
string endpoint = 'https:/sameEnpoint/leads/12345/'; //op3
```

I'm trying to use option 2 but only option option 3 get me a response 200 (resSystem.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]).

Option 1 and option 2 get me a response 301 (resSystem.HttpResponse[Status=Moved Permanently, StatusCode=301]).

Comment: if you see the difference is of one backslash is appended in the end of option 3 but not in opt1 and opt2. try to add  + '/'  in opt1 and opt 2.

Comment: @AnkurGupta Thanks this solve the issue!

Comment: @AnkurGupta They are slashes (`/`), not backslashes (`\\`). It's important to get terminology correct in computer programming.

Comment: Right @sfdcfox thanks for pointing this out.